I have the problem uploading the project to production
I have my project in reactjs.
I used npm init react-app my-app to create the project.
I finished it, it does work in development.
However, when I upload it to production it gives an error.
I consume api in laravel, it works correctly in development.
I compile the project and upload it to the main project for production. The main one is in wordpress.
I have reviewed my project and I don't find that there is a problem. I need help please.
When I see the url path I get an error in the console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.

Example:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Type-Options" content="nosniff">
    <link rel="icon" href="/league_logo.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site for carne employee"
    />
    <title>RRHH</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>


You need to provide code where you are getting error.

In your developer's console, click on the Network tab, and look at the response of the API request. It seems like it's returning HTML instead of json.

Agreed, my guess would be that an AJAX request was made somewhere and the script it was calling returned HTML instead of JSON (hence it complaining about the < which is probably the start of a <html or <DOCTYPE tag). Probably that means a PHP error message (formatted in HTML) showed instead of the expected response, suggesting the PHP script crashed. As above, check the browser's Network tool, find the problematic request and see the raw response, to see what actually happened. Checking the PHP / Laravel error log to see what happened may also be productive.Have you tried to debug yet?

I cannot share the code, it is the complete project that I compiled and when I upload it to production, in the url where it should be displayed it throws the error in the console.
In the Network tab, the answer is 200.

The status is 200, but that doesn't explain what the actual text of the response is

It's true. It's really the error:
304 Not Modified.
'content-type' header media type value should be 'text/css', not 'text/html'.
'content-type' header media type value should be 'text/javascript', not 'text/html'.
And the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Go to the Network tab, not console. Find the relevant request. Click on it. Then click the Response tab within that. Tell us what is inside it

Has the code changed recently such that it worked before but no longer works? If so, can you find out what changed? Ideally, we would like a the smallest reproducible example.

I added example

Thanks. So...what you've  posted as "Example" is the response from the API? Is that what you're saying? Well of course it's clear that `

`...etc is not JSON, it's obviously HTML.